# Regresson on 3d tabular data

Tags: machine-learning, regression

There is a dataset, where each Y depends on separate table :

[image]

Each table consists of the same set of columns, but the number of rows may vary.
Features in tables are both numerical and categorical (both nominal and ordinal).
Numerical features may have a heavy-tailed distributions.

I need to build a regression model, which predicts Y numerical value by table.

What is the common name of this task?
What are the methods for solving this type of problem?

Comment: You have row (0.3, 'a', 1) corresponding both to Y2 and Y1. Is this intentional? Do you expect Y1 to always correspond to one row of data, or could it correspond to three rows? Can Y take any values? Or is it strictly non-negative, or perhaps it can take only a finite set of fixed values?

Comment: @Cryo Y is one value to predict, in first sample y corresponds to table with one row, in second sample y corresponds to table with 3 rows. Y is non-negative for this task, but in general it can be negative.